# Why are these Javascript function producing different results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, animation

I have a function:

```
var myAnimation = function(){
    $(".next_action").css({'bottom':"-100%","left":"0"}).animate({'bottom':"0"},1000);
    $('.active').animate({'top':"-100%"},1000);
}
```

that takes two objects an animates them, producing a sliding effect.

In order to get multiple direction support, I encapsulated the positions in arguments:

```
 var myAnimation = function(inE,outE){
        $(".next_action").css({inE:"-100%","left":"0"}).animate({inE:"0"},1000);
        $('.active').animate({outE:"-100%"},1000);
    }
```

Which I can now call thusly:

```
myAnimation('bottom','top');
```

As far as I am concerned, these functions should be extactly equivelent, but the first works, the second does not. No animation takes place at all, the new object simple jumps into position.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{inE:"-100%","left":"0"}` creates an object with a key `inE` and a key `left`. The only time you need to enclose a key with quotes in JavaScript is if it is a reserved word (`if`, `else` etc), or contains control characters (`-`, `:`, `{`).

Instead you'll need something like this;

```
var myAnimation = function(inE, outE) {
    var animObjA = {
        left: 0
    };
    var animObjB = {};
    var animObjC = {};

    animObjA[inE] = "-100%";
    animObjB[inE] = "0";
    animObjC[outE] = "-100%";

    $(".next_action").css(animObjA).animate(animObjB, 1000);
    $('.active').animate(animObjC, 1000);
}
```

Which uses [square bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html) to set the properties of the objects